# Use Pygame mouse while hidden

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

Is there a way to use the mouse while,

```
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
```

is activated. Currently mouse only returns the bottom-right coordinate when tried to be used. Being able to get correct coordinates while mouse is hidden is required.

Could not find an answer at their [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved the problem by using an invisible cursor.

```
pygame.mouse.set_cursor((8,8),(0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```