# How can I make the cursor invisible, but still allow it to retain a x and y value?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

So essentially what I want is the cursor to not have a image or shape to it. My code, which can be summed up as this, is a game where a player faces towards the mouse position (using [`atan(y/x)`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_atan2.htm)) I tried using [`pygame.mouse.set_visible()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.set_visible), and while it makes the mouse invisible, I notice that the mouse coordinates are static and didn't move, and so the direction the player was facing always stayed the same. How can I get a mouse cursor that is not seen/visible but still can have a changing x and y value based on movement of the mouse/touchpad? Thank you, and if you'd like to ask me anything more about this problem to get information, please feel free to ask me in the comments.

Comment: Do you mean `pygame.mouse.get_pos` (or `event.pos` in the event loop) always returns the same coordinates when the mouse is invisible? It changes the coords correctly for me, even with an invisible mouse cursor. Perhaps it's a bug in pygame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found this question answered by the asker of it.

It looks related to your question: [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627934/use-pygame-mouse-while-hidden)

Simply, it is suggesting you to use this piece of code:

```
pygame.mouse.set_cursor((8,8),(0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

Comment: Thank you. If you (or anyone) can, can you please explain to me why that method works? The documentation says the argument is a `bool`, so why does this work?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.set_cursor) says that the arguments are _size_, _hotspot_, _xormasks_ and _andmasks_ . It also describes these arguments in a little more detail and if you expand the comments, there are some more examples. So the answer above sets the cursor to an 8x8 square, with a _hotspot_ at the top left. The bitmasks that would show the cursor are zeroes so the cursor is transparent.